# Best practice to test a python application which changes pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, testing

I am asked to demonstrate a small application which creates, changes and deletes records in some sort of "database". The requirement gives as example for a "database" a sql database and dictionaries.

I chose to use pandas dataframes.

A small part of the code I wrote is available here:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286438/asking-for-a-feedback-on-python-oo-design?noredirect=1#comment570229_286438

In that post I asked about general feedback on the OO design.

Here I would like to ask for advice on how to best structure the tests for this application?

Can you give specific examples of what tests shall I include? Also, I would welcome suggestions about the most suitable test runner (pytest or something else?)